# A question about quaternions and reference frames

Tags: physics, inverse, rotations, quaternions

I have 2 rotations represented by quaternions, quaternions A and B respectively. how would I go about finding the rotation from one refence frame to another, say finding the rotation of quaternion A in quaternion B's reference frame. Do I find the inverse of the quaternion? or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply your rotations like this:  $x\mapsto BxB^{-1}$, then I think you’re looking for $AB^{-1}$.

That’s the rotation you’d need to get to the result of $A$ beginning with the result of $B$.